# Using LINQ to get a distinct list of Parameters from a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

So I have List of reports, and each report object has a `ParameterCollection` (which inherits `CollectionBase`) which contains each `Parameter` in that collection.  I would like to get the unique parameters across all reports.

I've already got it working a longer (probably inefficient) way via looping through each report in list and then looping through each parameter in collection, adding to a temp list and then using the `.Distinct()` on that but I figured there was a better way with LINQ but I just can't quite get it.  Tried combinations of `Select()` and `SelectMany()`.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Orginal Code

```
var reportParams = SelectedReports.ToDictionary(rpt => rpt.Name, rpt => rpt.Parameters); 
var uniqueParams = new Dictionary<string, Parameter>();

foreach (var collection in reportParams.Values)
{
    foreach (Parameter param in collection)
    {
        if (!uniqueParams.ContainsKey(param.Name))
            uniqueParams.Add(param.Name, param);
    }
}

var finalCollection = new ParameterCollection();

foreach (var param in uniqueParams.Values.Distinct())
{
    finalCollection.Add(param);
}

return finalCollection;
```

Comment: share your code first to understand better what you get and what can be optimized

Comment: What is the type of Report ? Are you using DevExpress reports ?

Comment: @dariogriffo Added to the question, sorry for forgetting it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var uniqueParams = reports.SelectMany(report => report.Parameters).Distinct();
```

Edit:

```
var uniqueParams = reports.SelectMany(report => report.Parameters.Cast<Parameter>()).Distinct();
```

Comment: This one give me a type error: `The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: @Hershizer33, Probably because `CollectionBase` implements only `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>` so you have to cast it first, check if the edited version works

Comment: This works great getting it into an `IEnumerable`, but now I can't get the result of your code into my class that inherits `CollectionBase`.  I has no useful methods like a constructor or `AddRange` (I didn't write it and can't modify it).  Any thoughts?  I can always just do a baby `foreach` after you code to add each one into a `ParameterCollection` and that will be cleaner that what I have.